# Convert one column of multicolumn output REGEXREPLACE from string to number

Tags: google-sheets

In an expression of the form (one column in, two out):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,{"$1","$2"}))
```

How can I convert just *one* of the output columns from text to a number (like `VALUE`)?

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) says:

> If a number is desired as the output, try using the VALUE function in conjunction with this function.

However, if I do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,{VALUE("$1"),"$2"}))
```

I receive the error ("1" → 1 in this example):

> Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 3 expects text values. But '1' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.

How can I convert just one of the output columns to a number?

I have a complicated expression that produces output like this, and I need to `SORT()` on one of the numeric output columns, but I need to convert that column to a number or find some other way to properly sort it, because it sorts incorrectly as text (e.g. "1", "10", "2"), so if that's not possible, how can I `SORT` in numerical order on a text column in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the details of your use case, one of the following may be preferable:

1. Add a column with `=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE( B1:B100 ))`, assuming B1:B100 is the first output column. Then sort by this added column. This may be the easiest way to achieve the sort that you want.
2. Apply `Value` only to the first output. To my understanding, this requires splitting the regexreplace, so that first the replacement is made, then Value is applied, and only then the embedded array {...} is formed:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,"$1")), REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,"$2")} )
```

If you choose this path, you might as well have two different formulas in two columns, one `=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,"$1")))` and the other `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,"$2"))`. I think this version is the most readable and flexible one.

3. Apply Value whenever it doesn't throw an error (regardless of columns). This could be done with `IfError`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,{"$1", "$2"})),REGEXREPLACE(A1:A100,...,{"$1", "$2"})))
```

Comment: #2 worked best for me here, never thought to split them. Expression is so cumbersome that I'm generating the expression itself with a shell script anyways, so no big deal to make it even more complex. Great ideas. Thanks.